# Persistent Clock at the top of Console

Tags: c++, multithreading

I been trying to add a Persistent Clock at the Top Right of the Console and is independent from the other functions. My main problem is how to execute the Clock while im doing other instructions.

PS. Im very new to multi threading

https://i.stack.imgur.com/56Wh2.jpg

```
#include <iostream>      
#include <thread>        
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

using namespace std;

int ts=0;
time_t now;
void gotoxy(int x, int y)
{
    COORD coord;
    coord.X = x; coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
    return;
}
void foo() 
{
    while(ts!=1){
      time(&now);
      printf("%s", ctime(&now));
      system("CLS");
      gotoxy(50,1);
    }



}

void bar()
{
    string name;
    cout << "Enter Name";
    cin >> name;
    cout << name;

}

int main() 
{
  std::thread first (foo);     // spawn new thread that calls foo()
  int name;
  cout << "Enter Name";
  cin >> name;




}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be 0,0 at the top left? Also you'd want to `SetConsoleCursorPosition` before you display time. Still this probably isn't ideal and a UI application would be more practical.

Comment: You should also add some delay (sleep) in foo() so it does not consume the entire processor.   system("CLS") might be a problem too.  It will clear the screen after you write the time.